# Return first 8 characters of name

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to create a unique username for everyone logged into the DB currently. I need this to be an 8.8 format. Meaning the first 8 characters of first name separated by a period and 8 first characters of the last name.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Getting the first 8 is trivially simple - making sure they are unique is much more complicated. How do you plan to enforce uniqueness?

Comment: Are you validating the input from the server or the cliente side?

Comment: by using SubString http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx or Left http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx

Comment: What happens if the user only has 4 characters in their first name and 3 in their surname?

Comment: Although you do say "for everyone in the DB currently" rather than  "for everyone in the DB ever" so easy to determine whether or not this is true. What RDBMS are you using? How should shorter names be handled? If there are duplicates how should they be handled?

Comment: Sorry guys, this is for SQL server. I am not concerned about uniqueness. I just need to extract the data in CSV so I can populate a different system.

Comment: and yes. I am a little concerned about users that have 3 characters in first name and last name. Is it possible to filter that out somehow

Comment: How do you want short names handled?  `Joe.Smith` would be valid?

Comment: @user1366606 - Seems somewhat arbitrary to filter these people out. I suspect the majority of names are shorter than 8 letters.

Comment: Yes, i'd like to have Joe.Smith come out as that however names like Katherine Jones will need to be cut off at 8 such as Katherin.Jones and so forth.

Comment: By usernames, do you mean sql server usernames? Or your application's usernames?

Comment: application usernames.. this is just a table of first and last names

Comment: @user1366606 Then just the first part of my code will do it.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you would do something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT LEFT(firstname,8) + '.' + LEFT(surname,8)
FROM   tablename
```

The LEFT() function will return all the characters up to the amount specified, in this case 8.
If you really want to filter out users with names less than 8 characters, you would add a WHERE clause such as:

```
WHERE LEN(firstname) >=8
      AND LEN(surname) >=8
```

LEN() is a built in function that returns the length of your expression.

---

**Update**

If you are looking for users that are **currently** logged into SQL, as your question suggests:

Sql doesn't necessarily know **who** is logged in, only the **login** used. If your users are connecting via an app, the likelyhood is that they are using a shared connection. If this is the case, SQL will not know each user that is connected, only that a connection has been made by your app.

Try the following to see which logins are being used:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

Or, if using an older SQL version that doesn't support the above:

```
EXEC sp_who2
```

Although you can't join on a stored procedure directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could merely set the username as a primary key (garanteeing a unique quality) OR setting the column to be UNIQUE followed by specifing the length of the chars in the table to be 17 (8+1+8) chars:

CREATE TABLE users ( username VARCHAR(9), .... UNIQUE (username) )

or

CREATE TABLE users ( username VARCHAR(9), .... PRIMARY KEY (username) )

Logical behavior like ensuring minimun length is on the other hand not suited for the database, but rather the application that takes use of the database. If the input is to long, the database will complain (could just as well happend at the application layer), and if the input is to small the application could fill out the remaining.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what you are asking for:

```
SELECT
  LEFT(lastname+ 'XXXXXXXX', 8) + '.' + LEFT(firstname+ 'XXXXXXXX', 8) AS userid
FROM users
```

Adding the Xs pads out names shorter than 8 characters.

If you also want them to be unique, you can look at the ROW_NUMBER() function for each result. This gets pretty verbose:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(surname + 'XXXXXXXX', 8) + '.' + LEFT(givenName + 'XXXXXXXX', 8)
        ORDER BY LEFT(surname + 'XXXXXXXX', 8) + '.' + LEFT(givenName + 'XXXXXXXX', 8)) = 1 
    THEN
        LEFT(surname + 'XXXXXXXX', 8) + '.' + LEFT(givenName + 'XXXXXXXX', 8)
    ELSE
        LEFT(surname + 'XXXXXXXX', 8) + '.' 
        + LEFT(givenName + 'XXXXXXX', 7) 
        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(surname + 'XXXXXXXX', 8) + '.' + LEFT(givenName + 'XXXXXXXX', 8)
            ORDER BY LEFT(surname + 'XXXXXXXX', 8) + '.' + LEFT(givenName + 'XXXXXXXX', 8)) 
            AS nvarchar(1))
    END
FROM tblNames
```

ROW_NUMBER() counts the number of times the value has been returned and the CASE statement switches between simply returning the 8.8 or returning 8.7 plus the row number. You may want some further logic if you'll have more than 10 dupes (or if anyone's first name has digits in it!), but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: The upper select statement makes sense. However, is it possible to get rid of the extra Xs somehow? so that it looks like Michael.Jones instead of MichaelX.JonesXXX